# TMS Component Pack in new XE8 Trial install?

Tags: delphi, trial, tms, delphi-xe8

I'm having trouble with installing TMS component pack in my trial Delphi XE8 Architect dev environment. The pack is quite old, and I'm just about to use it, to check if everything is fine with my code, code was writen few years ago with this pack. Since I haven't got jet  registered version of delphi, I'm using this trial just to check if I can work with this code and components? I install tms exe but no controls are shown in dev enviroment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The pack is quite old.

That's the problem. You need to get a version that supports XE8. I expect that you can obtain that from the vendor's website.

Comment: Yes probubly it does not support XE8 because in install.txt I get in installation newest version which has instruction is XE3. :/ Thank you. Is there any good sit ewith step by step tutorials of how to install those components, because I'm new to delphi in general, and I'm having trouble with installing these components, even the trial ones I installed well, are shown in Tool Palette but when I throw them on form, and try to compile app, it throws me that it cannot find directive in uses statement.

Comment: Sometimes you need to save the form before the component will add the required units to the uses clause. So, CTRL+S, and then compile.